# Is there an easy way to slice any file containing planar or non-planar patterns for a 5-axis printer?

Tags: slicing, planar, non-planar, 5-axis, open5x

I am reading into 5-axis printers as shown below in a [modified Prusa i3](https://hackaday.com/2022/03/13/5-axis-3d-printing-for-the-rest-of-us/) by Jenny List:

[image: 3D rendering of a Prusa i3 with a rotating gantry creating a 5-axis printer]

The process of printing non-planar patterns on a 5-axis printer is intriguing to watch, as shown below by Garth Benson:

[image: An animated .GIF of a 5-Axis printer printing a 3D model]

[image: Photo of non-planar print (a clear, S-shaped tube) on 5-axis printer]

<sup>Source: [YouTube.com](https://youtu.be/lqxgfAbWB6U?si=CKAmuTboIiNk3h40)</sup>

The slicing tools available for 5-axis printers are pretty limited, to my understanding. Is there an easy way to slice any file containing planar or non-planar patterns for a 5-axis printer such as the [Open5x](https://freddiehong.com/2022/02/28/open5x-accessible-5-axis-3d-printing-and-conformal-slicing/)?

Comment: How are your Python skills? 

Comment: Good enough. Math however . That's why I added 'easy' on purpose.